# How to make ls permissions green colored?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I have the following scripts in my bash_profile, how can I make the part that displays ownership of a file in a green color?

```
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced  # List colors
alias ls='ls -GFh'                      # Preferred list implementation
alias lspermissions='ls -li'
```

`lspermissions` currently displays:

[image]

Comment: It only covers 11 attributes. Ownership is not one of them.

Comment: it's opensource, you can do it via recompile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Sure, the permissions are the second field so:

```
ls -li | awk '{$2="\033[0;34m" $2 "\033[0m"} 1'
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

I guess you could slip some ANSI escape sequences in there around the 4th field with `awk`:

```
ls -li | awk '{$4="\033[0;32m" $4 "\033[0m"} 1'
```

[image]

I am prepared to admit it is ugly ;-)

Comment: can you do it for the parts that display permissions like `-rw-r--r---`